# Best practices with Ember ArrayProxy

Tags: ember.js

Ember's `Em.ArrayProxy` and `Em.Array` have many programatic methods available for notifying observers of changes to `content`. For example:

- `arrayContentDidChange`
- `arrayContentWillChange`
- `enumerableContentDidChange`
- `enumerableContentWillChange`
- `contentArrayWillChange`

`Em.ArrayProxy` also has several methods for manipulating the ArrayProxy's content. For example:

```
this.pushObject('something random');
// Or
this.insertAt(2, 'something random');
```

When using the latter methods, does one have to use them in conjunction with the former methods? It seems silly that Ember's usually-automated property observers would require a manual kick here but I don't find [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_arrayContentDidChange) very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to use any methods in conjunction.

If you want to add items to your ArrayProxy, simply `pushObject()`. You would know this by just using the method and seeing that it just works.

From the docs:

> This mixin implements Observer-friendly Array-like behavior. It is not a concrete implementation, but it can be used up by other classes that want to appear like arrays.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html

`Ember.Array` is a type of class that in other programming languages (without mixins) receives the name of an interface.

> An ArrayProxy wraps any other object that implements Ember.Array

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

`Ember.ArrayProxy` is exactly what the name says, a proxy, that wraps around any object that has implemented the `Ember.Array` interface.

The other methods, that you mention, might be implemented/overridden if you are making your own "subclass" of `Ember.Array`. Some must be implement to make your subclass ArrayProxy friendly. Or if you want to add custom behaviour, maybe write to a log whenever `arrayContentDidChange`, then you override that method and add whatever logic your app needs.

That is Object Oriented Programming and all those explanations are out of scope for the documentation of any framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking whether `pushObject` et cetera trigger those events?

From the [documentation for `insertAt`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_insertAt):

> This will use the primitive replace() method to insert an object at the specified index.

From the [documentation for `replace`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_replace):

> You should also call `this.enumerableContentDidChange()`

So, yes, a properly implemented `ArrayProxy` will trigger those events when you add or remove things.